# Select multiple options from different categories with primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, multi-select, checkboxlist

I'm building an educational website with **JSF 2.2** and **Primefaces** and I'm trying to provide a webpage where the user can select what he already knows from a list of categories and sub-categories.
In few words I'm trying to implement a [MultiSelectListbox](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/multiSelectListbox.xhtml) where I can select more than one option and all the sub-options of a given category.

I'm thinking in using dynamic primefaces [DataTables](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml)(Group and Category) where I reload the category table upon selection on the group table to display the correct sub-options with an ajax checkbox so the bean recibes all the selected options.

However there must be an easier and better way than this one. The only condition is that I can select multiple categories of a group or the whole group which implies all the categories of that group.

Edit: A friend of mine give me a possible solution however I wonder if there is a more stylish way to do it, the **TreeTable** doesn't look quite aesthetical

Comment: If esthetics is an issue: Primefaces is fully skinnable with CSS. You can make it look like whatever you want. I think the TreeTable fits your requirements from a functional perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well a friend of mine actually found an easy way to do this by using the [TreeTable-Selection](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/treetable/selection.xhtml) element.

```
    <p:treeTable value="#{ttSelectionView.root3}" var="document" selectionMode="checkbox" selection="#{ttSelectionView.selectedNodes2}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        Checkbox
    </f:facet>
    <p:column headerText="Name">
        <h:outputText value="#{document.name}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Size">
        <h:outputText value="#{document.size}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Type">
        <h:outputText value="#{document.type}" />
    </p:column>
</p:treeTable>
```

You can found an example of the logic implementation in [the PrimeFaces showCase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/treetable/selection.xhtml).
Tree and Horizontal Tree are also valid options to solve this issue